# Maximum and minimum value of an algebraic expression when provided corresponding equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, maxima-minima

My mathematics textbook lists the following example:

> If $\ a,b,c\in ℝ\ $ and $\ a^2+b^2+c^2=1\ $ then the minimum and maximum value  of $\ ab+bc+ca\ $ is:
> (A) $\ \frac{1}{2}, 1\ $
> (B) $\ 1, 4\ $
> (C) $\ \frac{1}{2}, \frac{3}{2}\ $
> (D) $\ -\frac{1}{2}, 1\ $

To which, it says:

> Given, $\ a^2+b^2+c^2=1$
> We know that $\ (a+b+c)^2\geq0\ $
> $\ \implies a^2+b^2+c^2+2ab+2bc+2ca\geq0$
> $\ \implies 1+2(ab+bc+ca)\geq0$
> $\ \implies ab+bc+ca\geq\frac{-1}{2}$
> Also, $\ (b-c)^2+(c-a)^2+(a-b)^2\geq0\ $
> $\ \implies 2(a^2+b^2+c^2)-2(ab+bc+ca)\geq0$
> $\ \implies 2(1)\geq2(ab+bc+ca)$
> $\ \implies ab+bc+ca\leq1$
> $\therefore\ $(D) $\ -\frac{1}{2}, 1\ $ is the correct answer.

However, I fail to understand how that puts us in the confidence that no other interval exists for $\ ab+bc+ca\ $. Simply put, just like simplifying $\ (a+b+c)^2\ $ and re-factoring $\ (b-c)^2+(c-a)^2+(a-b)^2\ $ yield two different inequality expressions, how do we know that factoring some other way won't result in an interval that might affect the maximum or minimum possible value?

Comment: As rightly mentioned below, finding an example which achieves the max (or  min) value settles the question. +1  To find the examples, an easy way is to check when the relevant inequality can become an equality - in the first case, $a+b+c=0$ gives that (subject to the constraint).  In the second case, the sum of squares being zero can happen only when each term is zero, giving you the example(s) - there are actually many points which satisfy this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set $f(x,y,z)=xy+yz+zx.$  We know already that $$-\frac{1}{2}\le f(x,y,z) \le 1.$$
It suffices to find $(x,y,z)$ such that the values $-\frac{1}{2}$ and $1$ are obtained.

If $x=y=z,$ then the given constraint rewrites $$1=x^2+y^2+z^2=3x^2.$$ Also, $$f(x,x,x)=3x^2=1.$$ This maximal value is obtained in points $$\left(-\frac{1}{\sqrt3},-\frac{1}{\sqrt3},-\frac{1}{\sqrt3}\right) \quad\text{and} \quad \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt3},\frac{1}{\sqrt3},\frac{1}{\sqrt3}\right).$$

For the minimum, choose one variable nul and two others opposite (we want to obtain negative product), WLOG $$(x,y,z)=(x,-x,0).$$ Then $$1=x^2+y^2+z^2=2x^2$$ and $$f(x,-x,0)=-x^2=-\frac{1}{2}.$$